# Passing jquery variable into php script in a modal with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm having problem getting the value of a variable into the modal which is supposed to be openning. i have tried using post but nothing changed. Both codes are in index.php.

This is the jquery script passing the value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".issue").click(function () {
        var x = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {data1: x,},
            success: function () {
                $("#modal2").modal('show');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

And i tried echoing the id of class .issue but it doesn't works

```
<div class="modal fade" role = "dialog" id = "modal2" aria-labelledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true">
    <div class="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"><?php echo $_GET["data1"]; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the modal pop up show at all?

Comment: Your code flow is ignoring the returned value (which is, in this case, is the html from index.php with your data1 value in the proper place).  Nothing is changing in the page your on.  Maybe your confusing ajax and form/submit behaviour.

Comment: Yes the modal did pop up, but with nothing in it.
I don't get it, so does this means i should do something with the success function to make sure i get the value in the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the variable in the success method.  It should be success:function(ajaxData){}
So in all:

```
    var x = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {data1: x,},
        success: function (ajaxData) { // ajaxData is the return data from php
            // add the data to the modal
            $("#modal2 .modal-body").html(ajaxData); 
            $("#modal2").modal('show');
        }
    });
```

Are you sending the data server side to save it, or grab information from the database? If all you're trying to do is move the data to the modal, ajax isn't necessary.

Part of me suspects you're not properly calling and passing the data to php, if you really do need ajax. The php you send the ajax data to should be a separate file, that receives it, processes it, and echos it back to the ajax success function. Then the ajax function puts the data in the modal and displays the modal.

Hope one of those thoughts points you in the right direction.

Comment: well i was intending to pass the value in the same file, it works when i did it in seperate files. Problem solved, thanks!